# Javascript Ajax are not getting data in the dropdown Select tag in php (PDO)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

i am having a problem with one of my scripts , i wanted to show data on dropdown select tag but their is a problem with my javascript it's not working even the alert() is not responding maybe it's because of the functions i wrote. by the way php data is good and getting it's output from the pages in array format

**home.php**

```
                                      <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="label label-default">Country</span>
                                    <select class="form-control"  id="country1">
```

```
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="label label-default" >Province</span>
                                    <select class="form-control"id="province1">
                                                                            </select>
                                    </div>
```

> Now the Javascript Code which is creating problem

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
          function country() {
           $('#country1').empty();
          $('#country1').append("<option> Loading --- </option>");
           $('#province1').append("<option value='0'>--Select Province-- </option>");
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
           url:"country_dropdown.php",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
           datatype:"json",
          success: fuction(data) {
          $('#country1').empty();
          $('#country1').append("<option value='0'>-- Select Country---</option>");
         $.each(data,function(i,item){
           $('#country1').append('<option value="'+data[i].CountryID + '">'+ data[i].CountryName +'</option>');
            });
             },

         complete : function() {

            }
           });
             }
            $(document).ready(function(){

                country();

               });

             function province(id) {
               $('#province1').empty();
             $('#province1').append("<option> Loading --- </option>");
            $.ajax ({
            type:"POST",
              url:"province_dropdown.php?id"+id,
            contentType:"application/json"
            charset:"utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
             success: function(data){
              $('#province1').empty();
             $('#province1').append("<option value='0'> --Select Province-- </option>");
            $.each(data,function(i.item)
            $('#province1').append('<option value="'+data[i].ProvinceID+'">'+data[i].ProvinceName+'</option>');
             });
           complete: function() {

            }
             });

              }

             </script>
```

> My database Connection seems to be fine as both the files are getting the results 
>   **country_dropdown.php**

```
                <?php
              include('config.php');
                include('class.user.php');
               try {
              $obj = new USER();
             $stmt = $obj->getCountry();
             echo "{";
             while($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo '"'.$result['CountryID'].'":"'.$result['CountryName'].'",';
                }
          echo '"0":"Select Country"}';
            }
           catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
           $conn = null;
           header('Content-type: application/json');
           ?>
```

**province_dropdown.php**

```
                   <?php
                 include('config.php');
                  include('class.user.php');
                  try {
                $obj = new USER();
                 $stmt = $obj->getProvince();
                  echo "{";
                   while($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
               echo '"'.$result['ProvinceID'].'":"'.$result['ProvinceName'].'",';

                   }
                     echo '"0":"Select Province"}';
                   }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                  }
                 $conn = null;
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                ?>
```

> class.user.php file which has the functions to query the data ,they are also working fine but i think it should also be consider as any possible problem can came from the start
>   **class.user.php**

```
          public function getCountry() {
         $stmt =$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM country");
         $stmt->execute();
           return $stmt;
           }
          public function getProvince(){
            $stmt =$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM province WHERE Country_CountryID='".$_GET["id"]."'");

            $stmt->execute();
              return $stmt;
              }
```

[image: Screenshot of the pages]

The problem is in here as both these select tags can't get values as country value index correspond to the province , so province is dependent upon the country

Answer (score 1):

First, where is your event handler for when you change the country?

Second, you have bunch of typo-like errors in your code.

Here's some fixes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // cache the elements that you will be re-using
    var $country = $('#country1'), $province = $('#province1');

    // renamed
    function getCountries() {
        $country.html("<option> Loading --- </option>");
        $province.html("<option value='0'>--Select Province-- </option>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "country_dropdown.php",
            // typo: datatype:"json"
            dataType: "json",
            // error: success: fuction (data) {
            success: function (data) {
                $country.html("<option value='0'>-- Select Country---</option>"); // simplified
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $country.append('<option value="' + item.CountryID + '">' + item.CountryName + '</option>');
                });
                // attach event listener to the country dropdown, so that when the country changes, we load the related provinces
                $country.on('change', getProvinces);
                // trigger event listener ^ to get related country's provinces
                $country.trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }

    // renamed
    function getProvinces() {
        $province.html("<option> Loading --- </option>"); // simplified
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "province_dropdown.php?id" + $(this).val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $province.html("<option value='0'> --Select Province-- </option>"); // simplified
                // error: $.each(data, function(i.item)
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    // error: ('#province1').append(...) 
                    $province.append('<option value="' + item.ProvinceID + '">' + item.ProvinceName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // load the countries
    getCountries();
});
```

Another thing, the whole point of using [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is to avoid SQL injection. The way that you are using it is wrong in the second function.

**class.user.php**

```
public function getCountry() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM country"); // no need to use prepare() as you are not using any untrusted data
    return $stmt;
}

// renamed
public function getProvinceByCountry($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM province WHERE Country_CountryID = ?"); // notice the '?' ?
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    return $stmt;
}
```

You shouldn't need to build your JSON object. Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

**country_dropdown.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('class.user.php');

try {
    $obj = new USER();
    $stmt = $obj->getCountry();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null; //unnecessary

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**province_dropdown.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('class.user.php');

try {
    $obj = new USER();
    $stmt = $obj->getProvinceByCountry($_GET["id"]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null; //unnecessary

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: you solution looks promising but it still has some errors , i tried this for json_encode(); method and it works but still the problem on home.php with getting data remains intact.
               
             while($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $arr = array ($result['CountryID']=>$result['CountryName']);
              echo json_encode($arr);
                      }

Comment: Why are you iterating over the resultset and storing into an array? The resultset is already an associative array.

Comment: Because for some reasons it says unidentified variable with <br> tags etc type of error message and displays the Country. same with the next index country

Answer (score 0):

there are some errors in the script, i can't test the ajax respons by with the chrome console I found something wrong. i've tried to replace your script, it doesn't give the error in the console, I hope it is helpfull.

```
     function country() {
      $('#country1').empty();
      $('#country1').append("<option> Loading --- </option>");
      $('#province1').append("<option value='0'>--Select Province-- </option>");
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "country_dropdown.php",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          datatype: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              $('#country1').empty();
              $('#country1').append("<option value='0'>-- Select Country---</option>");
              $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                  $('#country1').append('<option value="' + data[i].CountryID + '">' + data[i].CountryName + '</option>');
              });
          },

          complete: function() {

          }
      });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

      country();

  });

  function province(id) {
      $('#province1').empty();
      $('#province1').append("<option> Loading --- </option>");
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "province_dropdown.php?id=" + id,
              contentType: "application/json"
              charset: "utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                  $('#province1').empty();
                  $('#province1').append("<option value='0'> --Select Province-- </option>");
                  $.each(data, function(i,item) {
                          $('#province1').append('<option value="' + data[i].ProvinceID + '">' + data[i].ProvinceName + '</option>');
                      }),
                      complete: function() {

                      }
              }
             } );

      };
```

Comment: No mate , it's not working. i have tried , also yes the error on the console is removed but i can't understand why the data is not parsing though javascript to the html tag <select> and <option> .

Comment: I've updated the province method, I've forgotten a  brackets. Maybe resolve the problem, otherwise I'll try to guest something else :)

Comment: ok, I found a little syntax error, I've just updated my code. the problem, maybe :) , was the way you've wrote "function" in the first success block of the ajax

Comment: can you check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/dp9pojk4/), where I've made the test. Into my console, now, there is only an error, the call to the ajax url that, naturally, don't works. Sorry I do not have other ideas

Comment: Ok i look into that.and can you give Up for my question. i will appreciate it.

Comment: try this for last try. https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/dp9pojk4/2/  I've also noted that the url where you insert the id don't have the egual symbol. bye

Answer (score 0):

The getProvince() function in your class.user.php code contains a syntax error here: `='".$_GET["id"]."'"` - It should be `="'".$_GET["id"]."'"`.  Also, when writing a database and column name I think it should be a period and not an underscore, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Well the class.user.php file doesn't contain any error nor do the getProvince() Function contained any error otherwise the data wouldn't parse through to the country_dropdown.php page and the json .

Comment: @JahanxbKhan, Oh, sorry.  You're right.  When I looked over the code I was using my new tablet.  My eyes are not use to such a small screen.  Now that I'm on my desktop I can see you are correct.